# CSS Sub-menu positioning works in Chrome & Safari, but not IE and Firefox

Tags: html, css, menu, navigation, submenu

I'm currently building a site for a gaming community, called `http://www.quad-gaming.com/`.

Everything is running smooth except the dropdown menu under "Login" at the right side of the navigation bar.  It works well in Chrome and Safari, but in IE and Firefox, it floats to the left.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Please don't create questions where you point to a website.  Websites change but this stackoverflow question will remain.  Would anyone want to land on a page where they can't see the source of the question?  Or worse: the source has changed?  It decreases the value of stackoverflow.  Edit the question to add the relevant code above, and ask a question about the CODE, not directing viewers to "go look at the site".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Indeed a bit strange.

If you specify the `ul` element to have a `left` value to zero, it works fine:

```
nav ul li ul {
  left: 0;
}
```

Can't try it on IE because I am on a Mac. Hope it works also there.

Comment: Going a bit deeper, this is happening, I think, because the `li` element is an inline element, if you change it to be a floated element or an inline-block element, it works without adding `left` value. I think this way is a better way —even if you need to restyle a bit your menu— to avoid further conflicts.

Comment: Adding "left: 0;" fixed my issue, thank you very much. Here is where I added it:nav ul li ul {
    position: absolute;
 left: 0px;
 visibility: hidden;
}

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
.dropdown ul {
    left: 0;
}
```

Tested and works on Win7 on IE10, IE8, FF20 and Chrome 26

Answer (score 0):

I've used

```
nav ul li ul {
    position:absolute;
    left:0px; /* Adding this to fix left position*/
    visibility: hidden;
}
```

And It works in Firefox.

Comment: This was what solved my question, but the answer above is more specific, so I marked that as answered. Is there a way to add you to "Accepted answer" as well?

Comment: You can mark my answer to useful... The main think is that you've fixed your problem.